# Android, when setting wallpaper (non-scrolling) still crops

Tags: android, crop, wallpaper

So, when I try to set my wallpaper that is the exact resolution of my screen, it still crops. Please note that I know how to disable scrolling wallpaper, that is not the point. The image of 1080x1920 is getting slightly scaled as in the image below. (You can see a little bit of the image above and below the crop section)
I assume this is to account for the action bar on the bottom or something like that, but how do I find the exact size of the crop that its doing, so that I can make a wallpaper accordingly. 
Any help understanding this is greatly appreciated. I am also interested in what element exactly takes up this lost space.

Image:
http://imgur.com/gWCnZya

Comment: Could you post some code pertaining to the issue?

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with code, please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error with pixel editing. I found that the crop deducts 62 pixels off the height. So instead of making a wallpaper 1080x1920 one must make the wallpaper 1080x1858.
I hope this helps someone else with the same question.